# SQL Server primary key on datetime field

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, data-modeling

I'm creating a new table in SQL Server 2005 that needs 2 fields: DateTime and MyValue (Int32). The DateTime field will be unique so I will be setting a unique constraint on it.

Which table structure is better and why?

MyIndex (PK, int)
MyDate (datetime) (IX_UniqueKey)
MyValue (int)

or

MyDate (PK, datetime)
MyValue (int)

My feeling is that I don't want an artificial PK (MyIndex) in this table because it is unnecessary and because the dates will be unique I will use them to access any record. However, it may be that it's more performant to have an artificial PK...?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use MyDate, MyIndex, MyValue etc.  What does the "My" prefix add?  Why not EventDate or EventDateTime, and [Value] or EventValue?  Also, if the date values will be unique, I will assume that resolution is to the hour or day.  If so, then better off using SMALLDATETIME than DATETIME.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, I think this was only an example, and the DATETIME can be to the second/millisecond.

Comment: Correct - this is a abstract of what the actual table will be.

Comment: I don't understand... it can be to the second/millisecond, but in another response you say: "So there will only ever be one record for each day in history" - are you sure you're talking about the same project then?

Comment: The time portion of the datetime field is not needed. If I were using SQL Server 2008 I would use a date type but as you pointed out a smalldatetime would be better in this case because we're working on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: If there's only one record per day, is there any reason not to use a daysSinceStartDate field as the key and just have it be an integer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you say the dates will be unique, do you mean you *think* they will be unique, or their uniqueness is guaranteed by the statement of the problem?  In my experience, some things turn out to be a good deal less unique than one imagines (US social security numbers being an example).

If the date values are not guaranteed unique, you should add the integer key.

If the date values are guaranteed unique, do they change?  If they do change, are they referenced by other tables?  If both answers are "yes" you probably should add the integer key.

If the date values are guaranteed unique, and don't change or are not referenced, you can use them for the key.  Regular DATETIMEs are 8 bytes and standard INTEGER values are 4 bytes which might have a minor effect on indexing.  If your date values are just dates, or only exact to the minute or less, and in the more restricted range allowed by the type, you can use SMALLDATETIME and get those index values down to 4 bytes.

Comment: The date field is unique inasmuch as its storing information on a per day basis. For example, daily visitors to a national park. So there will only ever be one record for each day in history measuring the number of visitors on that day. To your point smalldatetime sounds like a better data type for that field because time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

If the DATETIME value will be populated by the database IE:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
  (mydate, myvalue)
VALUES
  (GETDATE(), 1234)
```

...then yes, making the `mydate` column the primary key is the ideal solution.  If the date is provided by the application IE:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
  (mydate, myvalue)
VALUES
  (@my_date_value, 1234)
```

...assuming @my_date_value is not being supplied by the database - no, not ideal.  An datetime from anything other than the database can't be guaranteed to be accurate based on insertion.

Comment: The question is about uniqueness, not accuracy.  And datetime provided by the database is not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the guarantee that the datetimes will always be unique (think resolution of the time component), then creating the Primary key on the datetime column is a good choice.

If you are only ever going to be inserting increasing datetimes, then creating the clustered index on your primary key column is also a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, your intuition is correct. As long as no one can slip two (or I suppose more) simultaneous events in on you given the available resolution of your data collection process, you are hunky dory.