# Can I use a datetime as a key using code-first entity framework with mvc 4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to represent a workday as a class in c#/table in a database for an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I want to use code-first entity framework. When I  try to add a controller for the workday I get an error that it has to have a key/identity. I know I can just add an `int ID` field to make the error go away--but is there any way to tell the entity framework to use 
 `DayOfWork` as the PK? That sems the cleanest way to respresent this in a database. The day *should* be the PK.

```
namespace TimeKeeper.Models
{
    public class WorkDay
    {
        public DateTime DayOfWork { get; set; }
        public Boolean holiday { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the [Key] attribute to the DayOfWork property to do this.

```
namespace TimeKeeper.Models
{
    public class WorkDay
    {
        [Key]
        public DateTime DayOfWork { get; set; }
        public Boolean holiday { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

See [Here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391298/sql-server-primary-key-on-datetime-field) for whether this is a good idea or not.